# images not displaying with squid proxy page

Tags: web-server, proxy, squid, html

We are using a Red Hat 6 squid server to redirect HTTP request for custom notifications. Squid provides several built in splash pages however we are using a slightly customized one taken from a built in and just renamed it. When our splash page appears our custom image does not. The image on the web page is just a square with an x through it. The image file is on the squid server but the squid logs I think it tells the story. I just don't know how to fix. For example, there is a GET HTTP function that seems to want to append the name of whatever site the end user is going to, to the actual image location:

```
1457051968.734     14 192.168.150.125 TCP_DENIED/403 2881 GET http://www.google.com/images/image.png - NONE/- text/html
```

Problem is my image is not at Google but on the squid server. How can I override this? I have tried setting an absolute path in the splash page but that did not work. Here is what I have now:

```
<img src="images/image.png" height="150" width="250" />
```

The images folder is under /var/www/html/ and squid has rights to that folder. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your static resource path set in the squid config.
Relevant directives for this are set in

```
error_directory # path to message files
icon_directory # path to icon/image files
```

The path to the embedded image should be like this:

```
/squid-internal-static/icons/SN.png
```

**squid-internal-static** points to your icon_directory.

Comment: ok I added "icon_directory /usr/local/squid/share/icons" to my squid.conf. How should it be referenced in my splash page HTML? Currently I have  <img src="image.png" height="150" width="250" />. And this is still not working.

Comment: Logs still show Logs still show TCP_DENIED/403 2897 GET http://www.google.com/usr/share/squid/icons/image.png - NONE/- text/html

Comment: you have to create an image URI that starts with "/squid-internal-static" like i've written above. So your uri would be "/squid-internal-static/image.png". /squid-internal-static/image.png points to /usr/local/squid/share/icons/image.png

Comment: That's what I did. Here is what I have now. Squid conf = "icon_directory /usr/local/squid/share/icons". HTML splash page img tag = <img src="/squid-internal-static/image.png" height="150" width="250" /> = Now in the logs it shows TCP_DENIED/403 3051 GET http://localhost:3128/squid-internal-static/image.png - NONE/- text/html and still no image displayed.

Comment: we're using a similar setup with current build of squid - it's working with this setup. maybe there's a policy that rejects the request to the proxy itself and therefore the image cannot be delivered. URI looks good.

Comment: Its possible. What version of squid are you running? We are on 3.1. I saw where there was a bug fix for icon serving in 3.2. That may be what we need to do. ftp://ftp.arnes.si/packages/squid/squid-3.3-ChangeLog.txt. Or I may be able to whitelist one of our other servers and host the image there.

Comment: We're running current dev build in out test environment - currently 4.0.7. Offloading to a trusted source is also possible - and may be required if you'll add some additional features like AV scanning with custom reporting via redirection.

Comment: I'm going to have to post a new question. Its still not working with the image relocated to a white-listed server. Damn this is frustrating.  Hey on a side note- do you know of a directive I can use that will allow the page to come up after X number of seconds? For instance site A gets captured and the splash screen is shown. I want it to automatically go to the site the user originally intended after X number of seconds.

Comment: Of course - that's simple HTML and some lines of JS. I think you'll find the desired answer on google quite easily :-)

Comment: I have no idea how that would work using squid. You mean put the html and JS for the release in the splash page HTML?

Comment: That's how this works. It's just like any other website - you just shouldn't use any additional libs and more complex stuff - that's not what a proxy is made for.

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. Everything I see online whether is JS or in the meta tag - can you do a meta tag refresh without declaring the URL?

Comment: No. Just embed a small script of javascript that sets a timeout after x seconds and triggers redirection of the page. That's all.

Comment: Actually a meta tag worked!! <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="35" />